# Custom Callback Handler

Tags: java

I am trying to understand mechanism of callback handler. How is the handle() method invoked? Can anybody give an example of usage of custom callback handler (other than those used in Login Modules of JASS or so) in non Swing application?

Answer (score 9):

Define an interface to handle the callback.

```
public interface ServiceListener<T> {
    void callback(T result);
}
```

Define a method that takes ServiceListener as parameter and returns void.

```
Public void runInBackground(ServiceListener listener) {
    ...code that runs in the background...
    listener.callback(...data to return to caller...);
}
```

And you can now do this from your main code:

```
 runInBackground(new ServiceListener() {


        @Override
        public void callback(..returned data...) {
            ...Do stuff with returned data...
        }
 });
```

Comment: I need one or two concrete example. Can you elaborate little bit?

Comment: I can give you an Android example if that would be of any help?

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic example for requesting data from a webserver using the AsyncTask from an Android application.

First define the async class. Note that the constructor takes a listener which we use to publish the result once ready.

```
public class Webservice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private DialogListener dialogListener;

    public Webservice(final DialogListener dialogListener) {
        this.dialogListener = dialogListener; 
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        // We cant trigger onComplete here as we are not on the GUI thread!
        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        dialogListener.onComplete(result);
    }   
}
```

Basic server class for handling various network communications:

```
public class Server {
    public void queryServer(final String url, final DialogListener service) {
        // Simulate slow network...
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Webservice(service).execute(url);
    }
}
```

We can now use this code inside our activity without having to worry how long the call takes as it is not going to halt the GUI as it is executed async.

```
Server s = new Server();

        // Async server call. 
        s.queryServer("http://onto.dk/actions/searchEvents.jsp?minLatE6=55640596&minLngE6=12078516&maxLatE6=55642654&maxLngE6=12081948", new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String result) {
            toast("complete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            toast("error");
        }
    });
```